# Float elements/divs side-by-side without container width

Tags: css, css-float

I've come to a problem where I have 4 divs styled: `{width: 100%; float: left;}` inside `.container` which is styled `{width: 1200px; margin: auto;}`. Now I want my divs to float to left and all 4 be on the same line (side-by-side).

Now, it has to be done with `float` becouse I want to `margin-left` first div by `-100%` then `-200%`, `-300%...` to slide out of the viewport first div and show second div, then slide out second div to show third div... I'm building jQuery Slider and I want my divs to slide out, that's why I need them side-by-side and I need to animate margin-left. I know how to write jQuery code to make that work/animate/loop etc. I'm only stuck with CSS and floats, sooo...

Please, if you could tell me how to position my 4 divs (set width) side-by-side using `float` in a .container (width not set), that would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok. what you are trying to do would be (imo) just posible if you use absolute position on your 100% divs. Because if those containers use margin-left, the margin will always set the position between the inners div and never, as I think you want, with the container.

Once the divs are absolute positioned they are out of the html flow so your margin-left 100%, 200%, etc will be just with the container.

Also, if not absolute position, it would be absolutely imposible (with just css) to position the divs "side-by-side" out of the container and your only chance would be using `display:inline-block;` on the div and adding `white-space:nowrap;`to the container but then, as I said before, your margin-left will never work as I think you intend.

so this is what I would do:

```
.container {
    width: 1200px;
    margin: auto;
    font-size: 0px;
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
}
.container div {
    width: 100%;    
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

notice the height is set so you can see the results better in this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/9j518c0s/4/)**

scroll the window to check it

Comment: `display: inline-block` and !!`white-space: nowrap`!! did the trick! Even `margin-left` works :) Thanks. You have a typo it's `nowrap` without `-`. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to nest divs like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="outer"><div class="inner"></div></div>
    <div class="outer"><div class="inner"></div></div>
    <div class="outer"><div class="inner"></div></div>
    <div class="outer"><div class="inner"></div></div>
</div>
```

Then adjust widths accordingly:

```
.outer {
    width: 24%;
    float: left;
}
.inner {
    margin-left: -300%;
    width: 400%;
    height: 100px;
    background: #ff0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yu6abbhr/